# Wifi interface not displaying

Tags: wifi

I have a fresh install of elementary os and I cannot connect to wifi. Only way to access internet is through LAN. I found similar problems on this forum but none of them could fix my problem.

some of the commands outputs are as below

`uname -r`

Output

`4.13.0-32-generic`

`ifconfig`

Output

`enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:ba:4e:af:44:2d

          inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8955:f56a:c8a0:993/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3925 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3570 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3336376 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:627742 (627.7 KB)`

`lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1038 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1038 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:114664 (114.6 KB)  TX bytes:114664 (114.6 KB)`

`rfkill list`

Output

`0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

`lspci`

Ouput

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1576
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1577
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 98e4 (rev da)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b5
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723`

`iwconfig`

Output

`enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.`

Comment: please see this answer https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/20923/9445

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows PC, you need to reset your wireless adopter, by going into control panel select network and wireless-properties and reset that will do the job