# wifi not showing up at all

Tags: wifi, laptop, hp

hi im still new to linux and just dual booted my **hp 14-bs091tx** with windows, after the installation (and when on the installation prompt) no wifi adapter showed up even when using terminal to turn on the wifi it returns with no device available

also this two showed up in lspci

> 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
>   03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d72

3

is there any solution to this?
thanks

Comment: maybe the wifi is disabled and can be made availble with keyboardcombination or hardwarebutton on the side of the laptop?

Comment: no its not theres no such a button haha, its already working tho turns out i need to install d723 driver manually. so its solved. thanks for the response

Comment: @forevermore Please add how you solved your problem so that it helps someone else facing the problem. We love informative answers with step by step guide btw. Have a nice day 

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since forevermore solved his problem and, because they did not post their solution...

**Install Realtek d723 WiFi**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms
git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

For extra details and other methods of installing the driver: [Install Realtek d723 WiFi driver for GNU/Linux](https://subinsb.com/install-realtek-d723-wifi-driver-linux/)
Also, more detailed instructions can be found in [the driver's repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)

EDIT: I used the above repository to fix  rtl8822be, and also had to create a new file (`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf`) containing `options r8822be aspm=0`...